# Using CMAKE how can I use CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS to check a C++ library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use the cmake's function:

```
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(library function location variable)
```

How can I check if the C++ library are available ?

```
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(yaml-cpp "YAML::Token" ${YAML-CPP_PATHS} HAVE_YAML-CPP)
IF(HAVE_YAML-CPP)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "YAML-CPP libraries founded: OK")
ENDIF(HAVE_YAML-CPP)

IF(NOT HAVE_YAML-CPP)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "ERROR: unable to link YAML::Token")
ENDIF(NOT HAVE_YAML-CPP)
```

That code snip don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CheckLibraryExists` module only works for C symbols, not C++. Personally I would just use `find_library` and `find_path` to find the library and include path. If the library doesn't contain the right symbols, the user is going to notice soon enough during the linking...

Since yaml-cpp installs a pkg-config file, you can also use the `FindPkgConfig` module. However, since yaml-cpp itself is built using CMake, you should encourage them to actually install a `yaml-cpp-config.cmake` file. See e.g. this [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file) for more information.